# Insert query for HTML string containing single and double quotes

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have Sql  database with table name QUESTION

I want to insert value for QuestionTitle as html string contains single and double quots.

Insert query is

```
INSERT INTO QUESTION (QuestionType,QuestionID,QuestionTitle) 
VALUES("MRQ","QNB5T6TKDMS",'<h1>What are types of special symbols
like @.~!#!$%^&amp;*()_['"+-=</h1>')
```

When I try to execute this query in Sql  it gives an error ,unrecognized token: ""+-=')" .

I try for `\'` and `\''` ,still not work. 
How can I do this so that it will work for html string.

Comment: try using 2 times quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apostrophe`, or `single quote`, is a special character in SQL that specifies the beginning and end of string data. This means that to use it as part of your literal string data you need to escape the special character.

The first one works fine for **MySQL**

```
 INSERT INTO QUESTION (QuestionType,QuestionID,QuestionTitle) VALUES(8,"QNB5T6TKDMS",'<h1>What are types of special symbolslike @.~!#!$%^&amp;*()_[\'"+-=</h1>')
```

or

This will work in **SQLite**

```
INSERT INTO QUESTION (QuestionType,QuestionID,QuestionTitle) VALUES(8,"QNB5T6TKDMS",'<h1>What are types of special symbolslike @.~!#!$%^&amp;*()_[''"+-=</h1>')
```

Comment: The question has been changed from MySQL to SQLite. The first method doesn't work in SQLite.

Comment: second method work for me. i have to replace single quotes before ' ''

Comment: i dint get you please elaborate

Comment: i got it.for single ,use ' '.for double quote use "